# Getting geometry length in meters in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, line, linestring, parameters, length

In PostGIS, the `ST_length()` function returns the length of a LineString in some units, but not in meters.

Is there a function like `ST_Length()` but in meters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

St_Length() returns the length in the units of its Spatial Reference System.  If you want to get meters, you will need to transform your feature to a different SRS that uses meters as units.  This can be done on-the-fly, so don't worry about writing out another data set.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(the_geom,26915)) from my_table;
```

In this example, SRID 26915 is UTM Zone 15 N, NAD83.

Comment: Or simply add your own field and manage the calculation yourself. NOTE you have to write your own trigger or recalculate it on changes in your lengths.

Answer (score 28):

It looks like since PostGIS 2.0 (maybe before) you can also just do this with `ST_Length` by recasting the geometry to geography:

`ST_Length(geom::geography)`

For example, the distance between 50°N, 12°E and 51°N, 13°E:

```
SELECT ST_Length(geom) AS deg,
       ST_Length(geom::geography)/1000 AS km_1,
       ST_LengthSpheroid(geom, 'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]')/1000 as km_2
FROM   ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(12 50, 13 51)' , 4326) AS geom
```

which gives

```
       deg       |       km_1       |       km_2       
-----------------+------------------+------------------
 1.4142135623731 | 131.935962780384 | 131.935962780384
```

Comment: In PostGIS, this is now ST_LengthSpheroid not ST_Length_Spheroid; see: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Length_Spheroid.html

Answer (score 3):

Examples of SQL request: [how-to-calculate-length-of-polyline-geometry-for-several-tables-in-postgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32874/how-to-calculate-length-of-polyline-geometry-for-several-tables-in-postgis)

SQL request (length in km (/1000 -delete for meters)):

```
SELECT 
sum(ST_Length_Spheroid(the_geom,'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]'))/1000 AS km_roads 
FROM 
"D1_r";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula :

```
select ST_Length(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;'||st_astext(the_geom)),26986)) as geolength from my_table;
```