# Length of reversed geometry in meters

Tags: postgis, geometry, srid, length

I know that a similar question has been asked multiple times here (a great answer can be found here: [How can I get the geometry length in meters?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35462/how-can-i-get-the-geometry-length-in-meters)), but in contrast I want to get the length of the **reversed**  edge in meters.

I know that this is quite easy to achieve using ST_Length(ST_Reverse(geometry)), but look at the following queries (including their results as SQL comment; do not care about the id 1484 - it's just for getting a unique edge):

```
SELECT ST_Length(edge_geometry) FROM bolzano_street_edges WHERE edge_id = 1484;
--0.0007624185038570938 (length in SRID units... not meters)
SELECT ST_Length(ST_Reverse(edge_geometry)) FROM bolzano_street_edges WHERE edge_id = 1484;
--0.0007624185038570938 (length in SRID units... not meters)
```

This one works (meaning delivers the same length for the edge and it's reversed counterpart) and delivers the length in SRID units.
Since my SRID is already EPSG:4326 getting the length in meters is easy using the geography type of PostGIS, right? Let's see...

```
SELECT ST_Length(edge_geometry::geography, true) FROM bolzano_street_edges WHERE edge_id = 1484;
--84.58170640981749 (length in meters)
SELECT ST_Length(ST_Reverse(edge_geometry)::geography, true) FROM bolzano_street_edges WHERE edge_id = 1484;
--84.58170640981747 (length in meters.... with 747 at the end; not 749)
```

Hmm... now that's something **unexpected** (at least to me).
The length of the edge is not the same as the length of its reverse. I know that the difference is very small, but for me that's a problem since I want to find edges with the same length by using their hash code. Even with this small difference this won't work.

Another approach that might work, is to use ST_LengthSperoid instead of the geometry type. According to the accepted solution from the question linked at the beginning of my question this should give the same result...

```
SELECT ST_LengthSpheroid(edge_geometry, 'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]') FROM bolzano_street_edges WHERE edge_id = 1484;
-- 84.58170640981679 (length in meters... however, a bit different to the above)
SELECT ST_LengthSpheroid(ST_Reverse(edge_geometry), 'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]') FROM bolzano_street_edges WHERE edge_id = 1484;
-- 84.58170640981679 (length in meters... same result for the reversed edge.. great)
```

I do have several questions regarding my obervations:

- Is there a reason why the length of an edge is not the same as the length of its reversed counterpart when using the geography type? Is this a rounding error (or even a bug) in PostGIS or is this something expected?
- Why is the result of ST_LengthSpheroid not exactly the same as the one of ST_Length(geography)?
- Which result is the most accurate one??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Yes, this is a rounding error, a slight difference in the result depending on order of operands.
- Not sure what ST_LengthSpheroid() differs, but it's possible there's a slightly different code path still, as they originally had completely different code paths.
- You're talking about a difference of 0.00000000000002, there's no "most accurate" answer. (A difference of 0.00001 degrees is about 1m, so you're looking at a difference of about 2 [nanometers](http://www.nanooze.org/how-big-is-a-nanometer/): molecule scale.)

As to why things might differ at all, the [code involves a converging solution](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/C/geodesic_8c_source.html#l00677) so I'm not really surprised that order of arguments can result in a loop or two difference in when convergence is hit. Probably most systems that provide "consistent" results are just rounding away any differences long before a user sees them, maybe we should be doing more of that.

Comment: That the code uses a converging solution explains almost everything. Thanks for the information. I solved my problem by switching the datatype from double precision to real and using trunc after 10 digits when inserting. I do not need the accuracy (so saving some memory even improves performance a tiny bit) so this works well :-)