# SQL Query error: ambiguous column name geometry

Tags: qgis, sql, geometry, intersection

When I try a simple query

```sql
SELECT "Water_Service_Area_Boundaries_Non_Cadastral"."Network",  count(*), sum(st_length(geometry))
FROM "W_Mains_DSC_ExclAbandoned", "Water_Service_Area_Boundaries_Non_Cadastral"
WHERE ST_Intersects("Water_Service_Area_Boundaries_Non_Cadastral", "W_Mains_DSC_ExclAbandoned")
GROUP BY "Water_Service_Area_Boundaries_Non_Cadastral"."Network"
```

I get this error

```
Query preparation error on PRAGMA table_info(_tview): ambiguous column name: geometry
```

When I try it without the `st_length` it works to create a simple group with counts.

Also just the following works fine

```sql
 Select sum(st_length(geometry)), count(*)
 From  W_Mains_DSC_ExclAbandoned
```

Examples of the subset of the query that work independently but not when strung together

Just the total length

[image: example1]

Just the group

[image: example2]

When I simply add the st_length

[image: example3]

I have tried with .geometry in the `ST_Intersects` and this gives correct counts but gives the pragma geometry error when the sum is added

[image: example4]

Comment: ST_Length requires projection information (SRID)  see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35462/getting-geometry-length-in-meters

Comment: Your first query references two tables with the column `geometry`. You need to specify which geometry column you want to perform `ST_length()` on. Just like you specified the table for the `Network` column

Comment: What I don't understand then is why these 2 queries with the issues work when run by themselves. I'll add screen grabs to the question.

Comment: @she_weeds sorry I just realised that without the .geometry it wasn't giving an error but also wasn't giving a proper value for the counts so the intersect wasn't working. The issue with running the length of the lines in the network area still gives the same issue though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you do not need any *SRID* because you are not working with `ST_Length_Spheroid()`.

What @she_weeds is pointing on is indeed correct.

```sql
SELECT ws."Network", count(ws."Network"), sum(st_length(ws.geometry))
FROM "Water_Service_Area_Boundaries_Non_Cadastral" AS ws, "W_Mains_DSC_ExclAbandoned" AS wmain
WHERE ST_Intersects(ws.geometry, wmain.geometry)
GROUP BY ws."Network"
```

Comment: Thanks -so it needed to know that it's the geometry of one of the input datasets we need the length for.